# Pass variable to angular app to be global

Tags: angular

I need to pass a server generated string to the client, using something like php embed into html like:

```
<html>
    //head...

    //body...
    <script>
        System.import("app")
            .then(function(module) {
                module.main({authToken: '<?php echo $randomString; ?>'});
            })
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
    // end of body...
</html>
```

I got it in main.ts something like:

```
export function main(randomString: string) {   
    platformBrowserDynamic([{provide: 'randomString', useValue: randomString}])
        .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

and in AppComponent like:

```
constructor(randomString) {
    console.log(this.randomString);
}
```

After it I got

```
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?). ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).(…) Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).
```

How could I properly pass a variable to bootstrap as a provider and use in, for example, AppComponent or in other Component or Service?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To inject values that are provided using a string key, you need to use the `@Inject()` decorator

```
constructor(@Inject('randomString') private randomString:string) {
```

Comment: OMG! Don't know what i've forgot in my previous version of this, but it works like magic... At least maybe my question will serve as a complete guide for next strangers on this path. Thanks!